# Is there another way to print right angled pyramid in javascript without adding a line at the end of the display?

Tags: javascript

Is there another way to print right angled pyramid in javascript without adding a line at the end of the display?

```js
let hashKey = "#",
  str = "",
  space = " ",
  num = 5;

for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
    if (i + j > num) {
      str = str.concat(hashKey);
    } else {
      str = str.concat(" ");
    }
  }

  str = str.concat("\n");
}
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the adding of *new line* with a condition by using a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND) with `str`.

If `str` is an empty string it adds the emtpty string to `str`,
If not empty, it takes the next expression with the *new line*.

```js
let hashKey = "#",
    str = "",
    space = " ",
    num = 5;

for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    str += str && "\n";

    for (let j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
        str += i + j > num ? hashKey : " ";
    }
}

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`:

```js
const hashKey = "#",
  space = " ",
  num = 5;

let str = Array.from({length: num}, (_, i) => 
    hashKey.repeat(i + 1).padStart(num, space)
).join("\n");

console.log(str);
```